# I can't increase cart quantity value

Tags: flutter

I want to increase the quantity on cart but I can't. I showing error "======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following UnsupportedError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Unsupported operation: indexed set" while clicking on "+" symbol.[this is the image of layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9a8D.png)
This is my code:

```
         Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: value.hotelcart.length,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    // child:
                    // Visibility(
                     // visible: value.hotelcart[index][4] >= 0,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey[200],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                      child: ListTile(

                        leading: Image.asset(
                          value.hotelcart[index][2],
                          height: 100,
                        ),
                        title: Text(
                          value.hotelcart[index][0],
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          'Rs ' + value.hotelcart[index][1],
                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                        ),
                        trailing: Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                          
                          
                    **onPressed: (){
                              setState(()
                              {
                           value.hotelcart[index][4]++;
                       
                              });
                        }, 
                      ),**
                        // Text("${value.hotelcart[index][4]}"),
                           Text(value.hotelcart[index][4].toString(),),
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                                onPressed: () =>
                                    Provider.of<hotelItem>(context, listen: false)
                                        .removeItemFromCart(index),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        
                      ),
                  ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),`
```

I want to increase the cart quantity but it only show 1 that is given from list. It showing error on cat handling

Comment: Please explain you query & error clearly. Also reformat you code as its not readable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edited. Does is it okay?

Answer (score 0):

If your `Expanded` widget is already wrapped with `Consumer` there is no need to call `setState`
just define function inside your provider to add or remove and call `notifyListeners()` for example

```
void add(int index) {
    hotelcart[index][4]++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

and use

```
IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () => value.add(index),
          )
```

Comment: ======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following UnsupportedError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Unsupported operation: indexed set
this error occurred

Comment: can you please add provider code in your question

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/15AJ7mIjTMVc9lAAhXgjIqlVhlnJ4tiv9g68Xo_chZK4/edit?usp=sharing